# Clearing or changing styles with the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

On the TinyMCE tool-bar you can select a style to apply to the selected text (from a list of CSS classes that you create). However if I want to change to a different style, when I select a new style form the drop-down list, it just adds another class so the text ends up with having multiple competing classes attached.

Is this the normal behaviour - does any one else get this?

Does ayone know if there is a way to clear all styles on the selected text?

Comment: Yes, I have the same behaviour... So it is the way the system is supposed to work. But the guys on the forums seem to have found a solution: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21691

Comment: There is a button "remove format" in tinymce, you can enabled this and use. I hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit*** I'd thought that the optional Remove Format button (below) would do remove styles.

[image]

Actually, turns out it doesn't - not in the version I'm using, anyway.

So it seems re-clicking on the styles that is already selected in the dropdown is the only way to deselect them, short of writing a custom plugin.